# Load the source of an iFrame after a delay

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, load, delay

I have two iFrames on a Wordpress page that automatically refresh every 10 seconds, and I want to offset the time that they refresh by 5 seconds. I came up with the idea to load one iframe in when the page loads, and load the second iframe in after a 5 second delay.

So far, the following code waits 5 seconds to **display** the second iframe, but they still end up refreshing at the same time.

I have been working all day on this, and I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

```
<iframe width="100%" id="delayFrame" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
jQuery("#delayFrame").slideUp(300).delay(5000).fadeIn(400);  });
```

Here is the code that the iFrames use to refresh, located in the source file itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    var fadeInData = function fadeInData() { $("#responsecontainer").fadeIn(); }
    var delaydata = function delayData(){$("responsecontainer").delay('5000');}
    var loadData = function loadData() { $("#responsecontainer").load('display.php', fadeInData); }
    $("#responsecontainer").fadeOut(loadData);
    }, 10000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out with some help, so I am answering my own question.

If the iframe file has a .setTimeout function inside of the file, the file itself needs to be loaded in at a different time from the rest of the page, and the easiest way to do this is by switching the source of the iframe.

Here is the HTML:

```
<IFRAME id="delayFrame" src="" width="100%" height="500 style="display:none;">
</IFRAME>
```

And the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
 setTimeout(
  function()
  { 
  jQuery('#delayFrame').css("display", "block"); 
  jQuery('#delayFrame').attr('src','http://example.com');
   }, 5000);
 });
```

Now the display style switches from "none" to "block" after 5 seconds, and then the iframe changes the source, so .setTimeout **inside** of the iFrame is starting from the beginning.